# Rayleigh quotient for arbitrary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}.$ 
(a) For the Rayleigh quotient $\rho = \frac{x^T A x}{x^T x},$ show that there exists another matrix that will result in the same Rayleigh quotient for any $x \neq 0$. 
(b) Every $A$ can be decomposed into a symmetric and an antisymmetric parts:
$A =\frac{1}{2}(A + A^T) + \frac{1}{2}(A − A^T).$
Show that $\rho$ depends on the symmetric part only which means part of the
information in $A$ is lost when you use the Rayleigh quotient for nonsymmetric
$A$.

I can't find a matrix for which part a) is true. For part b) as far as I understand we want to show $\frac{x^T\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)x}{x^Tx}=0,$ so that $$\rho = \frac{x^T\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)x}{x^Tx},$$ but I also don't know how to do that. Any hints?

Comment: For (a) try conjugating $A$ by an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: For (b) distribute out the product in the numerator. Can you show that $x^TAx = x^TA^Tx$?

Comment: @Liam, I got part a), but still stuck at part b), can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the skew symmetric part of $A$ we have
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^T(A-A^T)x}{x^Tx} = \frac{x^TAx - x^TA^Tx}{2x^Tx}.
$$
The claim is that the numerator of this expression is zero. To see this, note that for any $A$ and $x$, $x^TAx$ is just a number. The transpose of a number is that same number, so $(x^TAx)^T = x^TA^Tx$. The numerator above is then $(x^TAx) - (x^TAx)^T$, which we just showed is zero. The result follows.